# I get a "Pending Error" whenever I click on Pay using Payola-Payment Gem (A gem made for Stripe) in my Rails 4.2.1 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activejob

Using Payola-Payments Gem to handle Stripe Payments, it's necessary to set Background Worker for your transaction. After setting up Background Worker using ActiveJob, I will get error when I click pay.

**Here is it**:

Note: Am using Windows Environment (Windows 8) and I believe there is something am doing wrong here.
Error Alert Renders on my View:

> **This seems to be taking too long. Please contact support and give them transaction ID: ook4dp**

**Here is the generated code from Console**

```
Started POST "/payola/buy/job/excelwithcode-7d492bf330ab66b0eaa61ce2ce277e14" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-25 20:50:26 +0100
Processing by Payola::TransactionsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"stripeToken"=>"tok_184FksCc1zXXaitaOrD5ELaH", "stripeEmail"=>"neededforpayments@mybusinesstest.com", "authenticity_token"=>"Uod7Ue4XHNcCvayA6G1shiiI43QKoBOrbImnwt0TGFHVlp11WdHaNTcPl/0UyYefcT6foowc30bFdtK0cJuXog==", "product_class"=>"job", "permalink"=>"excelwithcode-7d492bf330ab66b0eaa61ce2ce277e14"}
  Payola::Affiliate Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "payola_affiliates".* FROM "payola_affiliates" WHERE (lower(code) = lower(NULL))  ORDER BY "payola_affiliates"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Job Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "jobs".* FROM "jobs" WHERE "jobs"."permalink" = ? LIMIT 1  [["permalink", "excelwithcode-7d492bf330ab66b0eaa61ce2ce277e14"]]
  Payola::Coupon Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "payola_coupons".* FROM "payola_coupons" WHERE (lower(code) = lower(NULL))  ORDER BY "payola_coupons"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (1.0ms)  begin transaction
  Payola::Sale Exists (0.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "payola_sales" WHERE "payola_sales"."guid" IS NULL LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "payola_sales" WHERE "payola_sales"."guid" IS NULL LIMIT 1
  Payola::Sale Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "payola_sales" WHERE "payola_sales"."guid" = 'ook4dp' LIMIT 1
  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "payola_sales" ("product_id", "product_type", "email", "stripe_token", "currency", "amount", "state", "guid", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["product_id", 1], ["product_type", "Job"], ["email", "neededforpayments@mybusinesstest.com"], ["stripe_token", "tok_184FksCc1zXXaitaOrD5ELaH"], ["currency", "usd"], ["amount", 20000], ["state", "pending"], ["guid", "ook4dp"], ["created_at", "2016-04-25 19:50:26.639939"], ["updated_at", "2016-04-25 19:50:26.639939"]]
  SQL (0.0ms)  INSERT INTO "versions" ("event", "created_at", "item_id", "item_type") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["event", "create"], ["created_at", "2016-04-25 19:50:26.639939"], ["item_id", 2], ["item_type", "Payola::Sale"]]
   (150.3ms)  commit transaction
[ActiveJob] Enqueued Payola::Worker::ActiveJob (Job ID: 72e9235d-e2f2-42d6-8ae4-0a74dd8bce5d) to DelayedJob(default) with arguments: "Payola::ProcessSale", "ook4dp"
[ActiveJob]    (0.0ms)  begin transaction
[ActiveJob]   SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "delayed_jobs" ("queue", "handler", "run_at", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["queue", "default"], ["handler", "--- !ruby/object:ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper\njob_data:\n  job_class: Payola::Worker::ActiveJob\n  job_id: 72e9235d-e2f2-42d6-8ae4-0a74dd8bce5d\n  queue_name: default\n  arguments:\n  - Payola::ProcessSale\n  - ook4dp\n"], ["run_at", "2016-04-25 19:50:26.812282"], ["created_at", "2016-04-25 19:50:26.812282"], ["updated_at", "2016-04-25 19:50:26.812282"]]
[ActiveJob]    (87.0ms)  commit transaction
Completed 200 OK in 284ms (Views: 1.0ms | ActiveRecord: 244.3ms)


Started GET "/payola/status/ook4dp" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-25 20:50:26 +0100
Processing by Payola::TransactionsController#status as */*
  Parameters: {"guid"=>"ook4dp"}
  Payola::Affiliate Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "payola_affiliates".* FROM "payola_affiliates" WHERE (lower(code) = lower(NULL))  ORDER BY "payola_affiliates"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Payola::Sale Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "payola_sales".* FROM "payola_sales" WHERE "payola_sales"."guid" = ? LIMIT 1  [["guid", "ook4dp"]]
Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 1.0ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)


Started GET "/payola/status/ook4dp" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-25 20:50:28 +0100
Processing by Payola::TransactionsController#status as */*
  Parameters: {"guid"=>"ook4dp"}
  Payola::Affiliate Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "payola_affiliates".* FROM "payola_affiliates" WHERE (lower(code) = lower(NULL))  ORDER BY "payola_affiliates"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Payola::Sale Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "payola_sales".* FROM "payola_sales" WHERE "payola_sales"."guid" = ? LIMIT 1  [["guid", "ook4dp"]]
Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 0.0ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
```

**Under Network Tab from my Browser I get the following**

```
{guid: "ook4dp", status: "pending", error: null}
error: null
guid: "ook4dp"
status: "pending"
```

**config/application.rb**

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'
require 'active_job'
require 'active_record'
require 'action_controller'
require 'action_view'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module App
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.i18n.enforce_available_locales = true

    config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true

    config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job

  end
end
```

**model/job.rb**

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Payola::Sellable

  validates :title,
            :category,
            :location,
            :description,
            :company_name,
            :website,
            :email,
            :to_apply,
            presence: true
  validates :title, length: { maximum: 75 }
  validates :description, length: { minimum: 300 }
  validates :to_apply, length: { maximum: 500 }

  validates_formatting_of :email, using: :email
  validates_formatting_of :website, using: :url

  before_validation :provide_name, :provide_permalink

  def self.paid_ad
    where.not('stripeEmail' => nil).where.not('payola_sale_guid' => nil).where('created_at > ?', 30.days.ago)
  end

  def paid?
    (!(self.stripeEmail == nil) && !(self.payola_sale_guid == nil))
  end

  def self.search(params)
    jobs = Job.where('name like ? or description like?', "%#{params[:search]}%', '%#{params[:search]}%" ) if params [:search]
    jobs
  end


  private

  def provide_name
    self.name = 'excelwithcode' if self.name == nil
  end

  def provide_permalink
    self.permalink = "#{ self.name } #{ SecureRandom.hex }".parameterize if self.permalink == nil
  end
end
```

Looking at my development log, I understand the transaction keeps repeating itself because of Background Worker using ActiveJob which I set, **but the main problem is that the transaction never gets successful** and my Error alert responds on my Stripe Custom Payment Form as described above. In other words, once you click PAY, it freezes.

I still don't know why this happened and I need your help. Thanks for helping in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem.

The problem is from the Background Worker inside /config/application.rb

Comment Background Worker inside **/config/application.rb** and require other dependencies, such that it becomes this code below:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module App
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.i18n.enforce_available_locales = true

    config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true

    #config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job

  end
end
```

That will fix it.

Comment: Eh? The solution you posted looks almost exactly like the question. I have "config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job" set but am still getting this error.

Comment: @PrestonLee What version of Rails and Ruby are you using?

Comment: If you are using old versions of Rails lower than 4.2, as well as Ruby, then upgrade them. Then comment `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job` out of the way and run your process again.

Nevertheless, you might wanna use other Background Workers such as:
`Sidekiq (:sidekiq)`, and `SuckerPunch (:sucker_punch)`

Comment: @PrestonLee, another thing you could do to do away with the error is:


1. Don't comment `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job`.

2. Run jobs in queue by running `bundle exec rake jobs:work` from your terminal.

I think that will solve the problem. 

I tried this and it worked too.

Comment: I've tried both and unfortunately am no closer. This is ruby v2.3.1p112 and rails v4.2.6. I may try koudoku instead and see if that's any smoother to integrate. :/